# div content is not responsive

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm trying to get my page to pass the Google Mobile friendly test (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/)

Here's the HTML that I'm using:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 </head>
    <body class="body">
    <header class="mainHeader">
    <img src="img/banner2.jpg" alt="banner" />
    <nav><ul>
    <li><a href="link.html">na</a></li>
    </ul></nav>
    </header>

    <div class="mainContent">
    <div class="content">
    <article class="topcontent">
    <header>
    <h1>..</h1>
    </header>
    <p>...</p>
</article>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS that I'm using:

```
body {
  background-color: #A6A6A6;
    font-size: 85.5%;
    font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
}
.mainContent {
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.content {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}
.topcontent {
    background-color: #DDD9C0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3% 5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 600px)
         {
.body {
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 95%;
}
.mainHeader img {
    width: 100%;
}
.mainHeader img {
    width: 100%;
}
.mainHeader nav {
    height: 200px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul {
padding-left: 0;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
padding: 10px 25px;
height: 20px;
display: block;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
.topcontent {
    background-color: #DDD9C0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3% 5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
```

My code does not pass the google mobile friendly test.

How can I fix it?

What can I do to reduce the rate contact?

I have added:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial=scale=1.0">
```

But the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line of html between your  and  tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This section of your page is not responsive:

```
<div class="accordian">
  ...
</div>
```

Try changing its width to a fluid value like this:

```
.accordian {
  width: 100%;
}
```

You might need to play around with this value/section a little bit.